# If $V$ and $W$ are integer matrices, $W=AV$ and $A$ is unimodular is $W^{-1}V$ necessarily unimodular?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This claim was made in a proof here http://www.math.uzh.ch/index.php?file&key1=35477 on page 66, lemma 20. There is an obvious mistake in the proof with matrix multiplication. Is there another way to prove it or is it even true?

Comment: $A = W V^{-1}, A^{-1} =V W^{-1}$ are unimodular but not necesseraly $W^{-1} V,  V^{-1}W$

Answer (score 1):

How about
$$V=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&2}$$
and
$$W=\pmatrix{1&0\\1&2}?$$

Comment: What would be the $A$ in this case?

Comment: Do you know things like inverse of matrices?

Comment: Of course. I don't see what you are getting at?